# Allow user to select background from personalize screen

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

In my widget, I want the user to be able to set the background of the main page by selecting a picture from their gallery and then that image would also show up in a imageView on the personalize screen (so they know what the image will look like).
So far, I have the imageView set up on the personalize page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customize" 
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeBackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customizebackground"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the btnChangeImage is selected, it leads the user to the gallery, as seen here:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Personalize extends Activity{
Button button;
ImageView image;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String  selectedImagePath;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
                    {
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        try {
                            FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                            BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
                            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
                            bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
                            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
                            //Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image

                            if (fileis != null) 
                            {
                                fileis.close();
                            }
                            if (bufferedstream != null) 
                            {
                                bufferedstream.close();
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {                   
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }


        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    });

}

}
```

How can I make it so that when the image is selected, that image shows up in the imageview? Then, whatever image is set up in the imageview becomes the background of the main file?

Right now on the main page, I just have a default image set up:

```
android:background="@drawable/pattern1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your image from ActivityResult to ImageView:

```
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Save this image so you can use it again or in your main activity:

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}
```

Load your image:

```
public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) {
   Bitmap thumbnail = null;
   try {
      File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
      FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
      thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
   Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
   }
   return thumbnail;
}
```

Set the loaded image as Background in your main page:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, I add the "save your image" part and "load your image" part to my personalize.java right? Or do I save them to my main activity?

Comment: You can save it in personalize.java, context is given from an activity. Since your Personalize extends Activity, you use "this" instead of context. Use the load function in your main activity, again "this" instead of context and set image as background. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html SharedPreferences to save your loaded image filename, so you can load it again and decide if the user already chose an image

Comment: Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
I get an error saying that "bitmap" cannot be resolved as variable.

Comment: bitmap is your Bitmap object from "getThumbnail(..)". So for example you can write Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResource(), getThumbnail("yourFileName")); You are missing some Java basics you should know for android programming