# Where to Set Bitmap as Background in Java File

Tags: android

In my app, I have a imageView that collects the a picture from the user, saves it, and then is supposed to set that image as the background in my other activity. I can't figure out where to set the image as the background in my activity using this code:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d);
```

Here is the coding:
Drag_and_Drop_App.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Drag_and_Drop_App extends Activity {
private ListView mListAppInfo;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
public static AppInfoAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    // import buttons
    Button btnLinkToFeedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToFeedback);
    Button btnLinkToPersonalize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToPersonalize);

    // Link to Feedback Screen
    btnLinkToFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Feedback.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    // Link to Personalize Screen
    btnLinkToPersonalize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Personalize.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    // create new adapter
    adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, (List<ApplicationInfo>)  Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), getPackageManager());
    // load list application
   mListAppInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
    // set adapter to list view
    mListAppInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
    // search bar
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            // Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
             if (Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter == null){
                 // some print statement saying it is null
                 Log.d ("msg_error", "adapter_is_null");
             }
                Drag_and_Drop_App.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
        });


    // implement event when an item on list view is selected
    mListAppInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // get the list adapter
            AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            // get selected item on the list
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
            // launch the selected application
            Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
        }

    });

    // implement event when an item on list view is selected via long-click for drag and drop
    mListAppInfo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get the list adapter
            AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            // get selected item on the list
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
            // launch the selected application
            Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
            return true;
        }


    });

}
// load image from imageview
public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) {
       Bitmap thumbnail = null;
       try {
          File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename);
          FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
          thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
       }
       return thumbnail;
    }

}
```

Added coding:

```
        RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    yourBackgroundView = backgroundReference.get();

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            yourBackgroundView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        } else {
            yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d);
        }
```

CURRENT CLASSES THAT ARE RELEVANT:

Personalize.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Personalize extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button button;
ImageView image;
ImageView image2;
Button btnChangeImage;
Button btnChangeImageForIcon;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_2 = 2;
private String  selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);

Button btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);    
btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(this);
Button btnChangeImageForIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon); 
btnChangeImageForIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);


};

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b1 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b1 != null){
        image.setImageBitmap(b1);
    }           
} else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b2 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b2 != null){
        image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
}    
}
}

private Bitmap getAndDecodeImage(String  selectedImagePath){
try {
    FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
    bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

    if (fileis != null) 
    {
        fileis.close();
    }
    if (bufferedstream != null) 
    {
        bufferedstream.close();
    }
    return bMap;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {                   
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
return null;
}
```

public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
       try {
          FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
          fos.close();
          return true;
       } catch (Exception e) {
       return false;
       }
    }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what type of layout you're using, but you'd have to give the layout where you want to set the background an id. Once you did that then you should be able to use the following to set the background image using that id.

To set the id for the layout, just use `android:id="@+id/yourBackgroundViewIDHere"` in your layout, as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/yourBackgroundViewIDHere"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Your layout stuff here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is for a RelativeLayout (substitute your layout type if you're not using a RelativeLayout) and you could call it from onCreate():

```java
RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourBackgroundViewIDHere);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        yourBackgroundView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    } else {
        yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d);
    }
```

Comment: How could I give the layout an id? And luckily, the layout I want to set the background on does use RelativeLayout. Also, would I still set up the variable "d" by using 'Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d);'? Thanks!

Comment: I also get the error that backgroundReference cannot be resolved

Comment: I'll show you the code I'm working with (please check updated question)

Comment: @user1628978, forgot to remove that line that gives you an error, sorry. I updated the code above to show that and also added an example to add the id for your layout. Hopefully that fixes it for you.

Comment: Thank you, yes that helped. I have one last error. After the `RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById` line, I define my drawable "d" and in that line I get an error on "(getResources(), bitmap);" for bitmap.

Comment: It's not clear from your code where/when/how you're generating the bitmap mentioned in `(getResources(), bitmap)`. Please post all relevant code and relevant stack trace with error.

Comment: Please look at the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482828/allow-user-to-select-background-from-personalize-screen) it should have all the relevant coding.

Comment: Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503541/imageview-does-not-update-properly)

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you creating a drawable named `bitmap`. You have one named `bMap` and the `getThumbnail()` method returns a bitmap, but I don't see you using `bMap` or calling the `getThumbnail()` method anywhere to create the `bitmap` you're referring to in the snippet above.

Comment: I want to show the bitmap that comes from the user selecting an image in the first imageView for background (image)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39693/discussion-between-jason-and-user1628978)