# ImageView does not update properly

Tags: android

In my app, I have two imageViews that are the same size and both work fine. However, when I put a picture into each imageView and then try to switch out the top imageView with a different picture, the bottom imageView ends up getting the picture that is supposed to go in the top imageView. I'm not sure why this is. Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customize" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeBackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/customizebackground"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="100dp"  
    android:maxHeight="100dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
    android:contentDescription="@string/descForBackground"

    />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_background" />

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/personalizetextviewChangeIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon"
    android:gravity="center" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="100dp"  
    android:maxHeight="100dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descForIcon"
     />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeImageForIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/change_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then here is my java coding:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Personalize extends Activity{
Button button;
ImageView image;
ImageView image2;
Button btnChangeImage;
Button btnChangeImageForIcon;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String  selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

});


} 

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
            byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
            bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
            //Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image
            image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

            if (fileis != null) 
            {
                fileis.close();
            }
            if (bufferedstream != null) 
            {
                bufferedstream.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {                   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
}

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);

btnChangeImageForIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon);
btnChangeImageForIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

});
}

public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}
}
```

UPDATED CODE THAT I AM WORKING WITH:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Personalize extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button button;
ImageView image;
ImageView image2;
Button btnChangeImage;
Button btnChangeImageForIcon;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_2 = 2;
private String  selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

Button btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);    
btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(this);
Button btnChangeImageForIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon); 
btnChangeImageForIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);


};

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b1 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b1 != null){
        image.setImageBitmap(b1);
    }           
} else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b2 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b2 != null){
        image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
}    
}
}

private Bitmap getAndDecodeImage(String  selectedImagePath){
try {
FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
//Here you can set this /Bitmap image to the button background image
return bMap;

if (fileis != null) 
{
    fileis.close();
}
if (bufferedstream != null) 
{
    bufferedstream.close();
}
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {                   
e.printStackTrace();
} 

return null;
}


public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: `image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);` ???  Why not use two different references?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Initially, you set image to reference the top image view, `image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`.  Then you change is to the lower image view.  Then you change the image.  Why don't you use two references, e.g. imageView1, imageView2.

Comment: So I changed the second image to `image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);` is that what you mean? (just making sure)

Comment: Yes. When you want to set the top image view, image1.setImageBitmap(), image2.setImageBitmap() to set bottom one.  imageTop and imageBottom might be better names?

Comment: I have added the coding that I am currently using to the question. Now, I get the opposite effect of last time. This time, when I try to change the icon imageview (bottom), the image goes to the background imageview (top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same resultCode `SELECT_PICTURE`so the result can go to either one. 
You should use different result codes for the two actions you are launching.

EDIT

Code to help what was said in comments:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap b1 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
        if(b1 != null){
            image.setImageBitmap(b1);
        }           
    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2)
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap b2 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
        if(b2 != null){
            image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
        }
    }    
    }
}

private Bitmap getAndDecodeImage(String  selectedImagePath){
try {
        FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
        byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
        bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

        if (fileis != null) 
        {
            fileis.close();
        }
        if (bufferedstream != null) 
        {
            bufferedstream.close();
        }
        return bMap;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {                   
        e.printStackTrace();
}   
return null;
}
```

Comment: Whatever you want... This for instance in the beginning next to the other one:  `private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_2 = 2;`

Comment: I changed that and the instance of it at the bottom to `SELECT_PICTURE_2` but I still get the same issue when I run the program

Comment: try placing both pieces of code in the `onActivityResult` method instead of having this `SecondonActivityResult`

Comment: and please use a convenience method for all that image decoding, you are repeating way to much code...

Comment: what do you mean by "convenience method"? and now that you say that, I'm wondering how I can simplify this because I got rid of the `SecondonActivityResult` but then just created another if statement for the SELECT_PICTURE_2 code

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I get one error in that code saying that `        if (fileis != null) 
        {
            fileis.close();
        }` is unreachable code. I also changed my OnClick listener so that it would run the same OnClick method for both buttons (since they run the same method).

Comment: I updated my current coding up in the question if you want to see what my current coding is